# Can I use the source of an img tag to capture an image from a URL using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, image, rss

Assume that I can get the image source for an image from an arbitrary URL. That is, if the URL has a tag such as

```
<img src="image.jpeg" />
```

can I take `image.jpeg` and combine it with the URL so that I can generate a copy of that image and store it on my server? What I'm trying to do is grab articles from different webpages, but I want to have an associated photo to go with each article. I've seen some web services out there that can do this (Digg), but is there any way to do this with PHP?

Comment: are you asking if you can save an image?

Comment: yes. I want to write a php script that can save an image from an arbitrary URL (assuming that I can get the contents of the image tag source).

Comment: so you want to get an image from a website and save it on your own? i would have to assume that the website either has an rss feed w an image src, or that you are somehow able to crawl the page for a relevant image src because god knows theres alot of images on modern webpages... i know that you can get the contents of a page with a php function, as for a specific image idk

Comment: Consider a webpage for a news article. I want to get the 'main' image associated with that article. How do other sites do this, such as Digg, etc.)?

Comment: i believe they utilize the rss feed and get the 'main' image that way. i am not well versed in rss feeds, but i believe you would need to get your code to distinguish diffrent articles by section headers, then grab the image by some name/id that news outlet uses. this would probably be diffrent for every news website you are getting the image from. once you have the src you could make a function using the code i outlined below to grab it and put it on ur site or hotlink it (whatever), then you can resize it and do what u want to it. therefore i suggest you updated your tags to rss an xml.

Comment: refer to this, maybe it will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385629/how-to-display-image-in-rss?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

if you have the src then you can do a simple

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.someplace.com/image.jpg');

file_put_contents('/images/image.jpg', $image);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am able to create a file called image.jpg in one of my directories, but it is blank. Is `file_put_contents` only returning an image resource, that I then need to process using gd?

Comment: It should work try turning on error reporting in the script with error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT). Perhaps the site admin has forbidden outside referrals (side note gd shouldnt really have anything to do with this at this point bc ur not re-sizing or processing the image, just copying it)